# Not to scaffolding with Application Insights packages when creating a new Web projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

When creating a new Web project (WCF, MVC, Web API), Visual Studio always introduces ApplicationInsights packages which I don't use. I have to remove them one by one through NuGet manager. Is there a setting somewhere to stop such behavior of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add project at that time you can uncheck checkbox 'Add Application Insight to Project' on right side please see screen shot

[Please see screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTLjG.png)